# How to hide custom field text if field left blank

Tags: custom-fields, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a site with a form created with gravity forms.  The visitor fills out this form and it populates a custom post type.  The fields that the user completes are custom fields that I have created with the plugin "Advanced custom fields".

The form has a series of questions that the user fills out, but will leave some blank, as they are not all required.

This is the code used for the output:

I need to figure out how to hide the text 'Birthday' if the birthday field is left blank.

Comment: sorry the code did not display...here is it: <div class="form-question"><?php echo 'Birthday:' ?></div> <div class="form-answer"><?php the_field('birthday'); ?></div>

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this:

```
<?php 
if( get_field( "birthday" ) ) {
    the_field( "birthday" );
}
?>
```

Source: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/the_field/